# Azure Function Apps: Integration of Flask framework with Azure functions

Tags: python, azure, rest, flask, azure-functions

I have a azure function that will consume the data from an event hub and redirect the same data to an REST API.
I have already written a set of code which is will redirect redirect the **Event hub** output to the API(testing pending) but now I want to integrate the flask framework with my existing code but I don't know what changes I should made to the following code so that I can use the

```
======================================================================================================
__init__.py
======================================================================================================
from PWO_EventHubTrigger.postCall import GetPost
from typing import List
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import datetime
import json


storage_connection_string = os.getenv('eh_rec_storage_connection_string_FromKeyVault')
logging.info('storage_connection_string: %s', storage_connection_string)

container_name = os.getenv('eh_rec_storage_container_name_FromKeyVault')
logging.info('container_name: %s', container_name)

today = datetime.datetime.today()


def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    logging.info('-----------main function starts-----------')
    try:
        for event in events:
            data = event.get_body().decode('utf-8')
            json.loads(data)
            logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s', data)
            logging.info(f'  SequenceNumber = {event.sequence_number}')
            logging.info(f'  Offset = {event.offset}')
            
            try:
                logging.info("Calling GetPost method from main")
                res = GetPost(data)
                logging.info("GetPost response recived: ", res)
            except Exception as Argument: 
                logging.exception("Error occurred during the GetPost method")
            
    except Exception as Argument: 
        logging.exception("Error occured in main") 

======================================================================================================
postcall.py
======================================================================================================
import requests
import logging
 
# data={'number': 12524, 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'}
# data = {"Source": "localhost", "Timestamp": "2021-05-14 14:30:00","Tags": [{"TagName": "testtag1","TagValue": "10.52","TagQuality": 192}]}
def GetPost(data):
    logging.info('-----------GetPost function starts-----------')
    try: 
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'customize header string', 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }  
        response = requests.post('https://10.199.215.156:443/RestEndpoint', data= data, headers=headers, timeout=3) 
        # response = requests.post('http://bugs.python.org', data= data, headers=headers, timeout=3)
        print("Http response code:", response.status_code) 
        # print("Http response text:", response.text) 
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise error in case of failure 
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as httpErr: 
        logging.info('Http Error:', httpErr)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as connErr: 
        logging.info('Error Connecting:', connErr)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as timeOutErr: 
        logging.info('Timeout Error:', timeOutErr)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as reqErr:  
        logging.info('Something Else:', reqErr)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.info('Something Else:', err)
======================================================================================================
function.json --> Azure configuration file
======================================================================================================
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "my-events",
      "connection": "EventHubReceiverPolicy_FromKeyVault",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "dataType": "binary"
    }
  ]
}

======================================================================================================
local.settings.json --> Azure configuration file
======================================================================================================
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Endpoint1>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "storage_connection_string_FromKeyVault": "<connectionString",
    "storage_container_name_FromKeyVault": "<container_name>",
    "EventHubReceiverPolicy_FromKeyVault": "<Endpoint2>"
  }
}
```

I am newbie to python development. Apologies if you think my question is silly. Many thanks !!

Comment: Is there something specific you need Flask for, you didn't finish your explanation? You don't need Flask to run an Azure Function so it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @StanleyGong  - `No`, no one will call the function except the Eventhub.. so even ever a new data arrives to the Event hub then the function will trigger itself and will redirect the data to an REST API. So just want to know that would it be useful to integrate any framework with the azure function.. if yes.. then how ??

Comment: @Stark, I see, so event hub data will be posted to your flask app? Is `10.199.215.156` your flask app public ip? If yes, may I know what issue that you are facing?

Comment: @StanleyGong - `No`, I just want to know -Can I develop a Azure functions with the help of an Framework.

Comment: @StanleyGong - The aim of the azure function is consume the data from a Eventhub and redirect this data to a REST API. That REST API exist in a private network.

Comment: Your Azure function resides in a public network, so it is unable to access a private IP address. You can refer to this doc to integrate your Azure function with a private network:
 https://www.stefanroth.net/2019/01/13/azure-functions-azure-functions-using-hybrid-connections/

Comment: @StanleyGong I have created a hybrid connection in Azure Function Apps.

Comment: @Stark, here is a workaround: just storing event hub data into Azure storage using your Azure function, and implement a corn job(maybe once per 30 mins) in your flask app to read these files from storage and then handle them.

Comment: @StanleyGong but I think there is no need to keep the data to blob and wait for 30moins.. better we forward the data to rest api on real time basis.

Comment: @Stark, yes but seems you have a network connection issue while you are using the hybrid connection so I think this workaround should be fit for you, You can also cut down the waiting time, i,e 10 mins or 5 mins and filter blobs by blob `created time` property

Comment: @StanleyGong I have not tested my connectivity but assuming that hybrid connection should work.. yet to receive credentials from the API owner.. once I get it then will start testing.. If we are able to connect then can we use the azure function with Flask ?? Would it be right idea to use any framework in azure functions??

Comment: @Stark, Yes, I think you are on the right way. If you can run your function code inside of the flask app network, you can try this directly.

Comment: @StanleyGong can you please elaborate the procedure.. literally I have no idea how to proceed.. pls help..

Comment: @Stark, if you reside in the flask app network , just follow this doc to run azure function code locally:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python#run-the-function-locally , so that you can try your code without network connection issue.

Comment: @StanleyGong this document is about debug the code is local.. that I am able run in local environment..

Comment: @StanleyGong what I want to know `Would it be right idea to use any framework in azure functions??`

Comment: @Stark, if you want to use HTTP post request to send data from your Azure function to your flask app, my answer is Yes, this is the right idea.

Comment: @StanleyGong I really do not have much information about the endpoint except the IP as of now.. what else I should know before sending the request to the REST API? if that API is not build using the FLASK then I should not go try to use the Flask framework along with Azure functions. Right??

Comment: @StanleyGong one thing I could not understand that why should I use Flask at my end only iff the REST API is also build using the Flask. Is there any dependency or performance improvement??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234266/discussion-between-stark-and-stanley-gong).